# How to search string with no quotes?

Tags: python-3.x

My objective is to find a string without single quotes and then replaced it  to other value. I getting this kind of string from server which can be changed with respect to situation:

```
field_domain = "['|', ('company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]"
```

I am trying such that i should get only **company_id** or any string which is without single inverted quotes.

So if i write `field_domain.find("company_id")` and it `returns 8` which is 'company_id' first letter `'c'`

For checking i write `field_domain[8:]` and it gave me that:

`"company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]"`

which is giving the index of single quoted company_id

Any solution? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Is this a JSON format that you're trying to read?  Parsers for that are already built into Python and are very easy to use.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you suggest a solution. Json one.

Comment: Check out the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and any of the thousands of JSON questions here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

ok i derived like that. If any other can suggest a solution i will be happily take part on that too.

```
import re

# Original string
field_domain = "['|', ('company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]"

# Extract strings that end with ')' and their indices, exclude strings with False)
matches = [(m.group(0), m.start()) for m in re.finditer(r'\b\w+\b\)', field_domain) if 'False)' not in m.group(0)]

# Convert list of tuples to list of strings
result_list = [f"{match[0]} ({match[1]})" for match in matches]

# Convert list to string
result_string = ' '.join(result_list)

# Output
print(result_string)
```